# Sending a variable between activity and fragment for managment of back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am new in android. I know maybee my question is duplicate but i can't solve my problem. I have one activity and some fragments. When clicked on a Button, i handle 10buttons in this P fragment. I want to manage back button and i use this code for management. but i don't know when i am in P fragment, how can i manage back button? how can i add my fragments to my stack???

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public Stack <Fragment> mFragmentStack=new Stack <Fragment>();
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btnProduct.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn3:
            Fragment product=new Product();
            Log.e("button", "3Click");
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
            //ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new Product());

            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragmentStack.push(product));
            ft.commit();
            break;
                     }
    }

     };

        @Override
       public void onBackPressed(){
          mFragmentStack.pop();
           if(mFragmentStack.size()>0){
        FragmentTransaction fTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragmentStack.peek());
        fTransaction.commit();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

P.java:

```
 public class P extends Fragment implements AnimationListener{
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_view, container, false);
            return view;
}
     private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1_product:
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new CustomizedDevelopment());
            ft.commit();
            break;
               }
    }

};
 }
```

I want when i clicked on the back button when i am in P fragment, back button shows previous page in P fragment.

Thanks for help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call commit(),  you might want to call addToBackStack(), in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button. so just do `ft.addToBackStack(null);` before you call commit.

Comment: This is worked but i set animation for transaction between fragments and when i use this, when clicked on the back button, the animation not shows:( How can solve this?

Comment: Found in the docs this:

Change:

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out);
To:

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out, R.anim.hyperspace_in, R.anim.slide_out );
and now the backstack animates - In reverse!!

Comment: ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out, R.anim.hyperspace_in, R.anim.slide_out); use this to have the reverse animation when back pressed

Answer (score 0):

Better to override the onBackpressed in fragemnt activity

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

it will handles the back functionality of the screen.

meanwhile u can write the keylisteners also.